# Why does fork return 0 for child and return the child's PID for parent and not VICE VERSA?

Tags: process, fork, child-process

I know that when you call fork() a child process is created and returns a value of 0 to the child process and returns the process ID of the child process to the parent process.  Otherwise, a value of -1 is returned to the parent process, no
child process is created, and the global variable errno is set to indicate the error. ([How does fork() return for child process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562602/how-does-fork-return-for-child-process))

I know this because my professor said it to me, I can search the net and get the answer etc. But I can't find why it isn't vice versa?

For example parent get 0 and child 12867235. Does anyone have a good explanation on this?

Thansk in advance and excuse my English.

Answer (score 4):

The return value from fork() in the parent, is how the parent finds out the PID of the child process.

The child process doesn't need to find out its PID from the fork() call, since it can call getpid(), and find out its parent's PID with getppid().