# How does fork() know when to return 0?

Tags: c, unix, process, fork, internals

Take the following example:

```
int main(void)
{
     pid_t  pid;

     pid = fork();
     if (pid == 0) 
          ChildProcess();
     else 
          ParentProcess();
}
```

So correct me if I am wrong, once fork() executes a child process is created. Now going by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2562743/5826291) fork() returns twice. That is once for the parent process and once for the child process.

Which means that two separate processes come into existence DURING the fork call and not after it ending.

Now I don't get it how it understands how to return 0 for the child process and the correct PID for the parent process.

This where it gets really confusing. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23819945/5826291) states that fork() works by copying the context information of the process and manually setting the return value to 0.

First am I right in saying that the return to any function is placed in a single register? **Since in a single processor environment a process can call only one subroutine that returns only one value (correct me if I am wrong here).**

**Let's say I call a function foo() inside a routine and that function returns a value, that value will be stored in a register say BAR. Each time a function wants to return a value it will use a particular processor register.** So if I am able to manually change the return value in the process block I am able to change the value returned to the function right?

***So am I correct in thinking that is how fork() works?***

Comment: There is no "it" to return two values at once. When `fork` is called, the OS takes over. It creates two copies of the process, identical in all respects except the contents of one memory location. That memory location happens to be one that ends up being returned from `fork`.

Comment: *'two separate processes come into existence DURING the fork call'* - no, one is already in existence. A second process comes into existence during the fork call.

Comment: @n.m. Though that's not even necessary. Application or library code could store the result of `getpid` in a variable. Then when the OS returns, it could call `getpid` again. In the parent, the two will match. In the child, they will not. All you need is something, anything, that you can test that's different int he two, and the PID qualifies.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz But then how does the parent get the child's PID?

Comment: @SebastianRedl Any way it wants to. Once each process knows which is which, there's no further issues at all. For example, the system call could return the child's PID to both processes and the child could ignore it while the parent returns it. The only problem you need to solve is how each process knows which one it is, after that, anything else can be solved by providing the same information to both processes and having the "wrong" process ignore it.

Answer (score 57):

*How* it works is largely irrelevant - as a developer working at a certain level (ie, coding to the UNIX APIs), you really only need to know *that* it works.

Having said that however, and recognising that curiosity or a need to understand at some depth is generally a good trait to have, there are any number of ways that this *could* be done.

First off, your contention that a function can only return one value is correct as far as it goes but you need to remember that, after the process split, there are actually *two* instances of the function running, one in each process. They're mostly independent of each other and can follow different code paths. The following diagram may help in understanding this:

```
Process 314159 | Process 271828
-------------- | --------------
runs for a bit |
calls fork     |
               | comes into existence
returns 271828 | returns 0
```

You can hopefully see there that a *single* instance of `fork` can only return one value (as per any other C function) but there are actually multiple instances running, which is why it's said to return multiple values in the documentation.

---

Here's one possibility on how it *could* work.

When the `fork()` function starts running, it stores the current process ID (PID).

Then, when it comes time to return, if the PID is the same as that stored, it's the parent. Otherwise it's the child. Pseudo-code follows:

```
def fork():
    saved_pid = getpid()

    # Magic here, returns PID of other process or -1 on failure.

    other_pid = split_proc_into_two();

    if other_pid == -1:        # fork failed -> return -1
        return -1

    if saved_pid == getpid():  # pid same, parent -> return child PID
        return other_pid

    return 0                   # pid changed, child, return zero
```

Note that there's a lot of magic in the `split_proc_into_two()` call and it almost certainly won't work that way at all under the covers<sup>(a)</sup>. It's just to illustrate the concepts around it, which is basically:

- get the original PID before the split, which will remain identical for both processes after they split.
- do the split.
- get the current PID after the split, which will be *different* in the two processes.

You may also want to take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653340/differences-between-exec-and-fork/1653415#1653415), it explains the `fork/exec` philosophy.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> It's almost certainly more complex than I've explained. For example, in MINIX, the call to `fork` ends up running in the kernel, which has access to the entire process tree.

It simply copies the parent process structure into a free slot for the child, along the lines of:

```
sptr = (char *) proc_addr (k1); // parent pointer
chld = (char *) proc_addr (k2); // child pointer
dptr = chld;
bytes = sizeof (struct proc);   // bytes to copy
while (bytes--)                 // copy the structure
    *dptr++ = *sptr++;
```

Then it makes slight modifications to the child structure to ensure it will be suitable, including the line:

```
chld->p_reg[RET_REG] = 0;       // make sure child receives zero
```

So, basically identical to the scheme I posited, but using data modifications rather than code path selection to decide what to return to the caller - in other words, you'd see something like:

```
return rpc->p_reg[RET_REG];
```

at the end of `fork()` so that the correct value gets returned depending on whether it's the parent or child process.

Comment: `fork()` returns the `PID` of the child in the parent and returns `0` in the child, so it returns **two** values, one in parent (PID) and one in child (0) (on success...)

Comment: @ralfhtp, that depends entirely on your definition of "it". A single instance of `fork` returns only *one* value, it's just there are now *two* copies, one each in the child and parent process.

Comment: yes, in code you call `fork()` once and then it magically doubles itself... like a fork ...

Comment: @paxdiablo Okay, your method is valid, but am I right in saying that at a time only one value can be returned by a routine in a process ? So there can be only one ret_val, if I change that then I can change whatever value that is returned. Am I right  ?

Comment: @Machina333, yes, in terms of the C "virtual device" environment that the standard describes, only one value can be returned from a function. Forking operates outside the scope of the standard so the standard only really applies to a single instance.

Comment: Note that the `setjmp` function can return more than once in a single process.

Comment: Not enough JQuery. "How it works is largely irrelevant" to you perhaps. But the question is clear, OP is asking precisely "how".

Comment: @paxdiablo: No, fork only returns a single value.  It's just that after the call to fork, there are two separate processes running, and fork returns a different value in each.  It's really no different than if you had two instances of a program running, and some function call within the program returned different values depending on the state of each instance.

Comment: @jamesqf, I'm not sure why you actually think that is disagreeing with my answer and comments. I clearly state that a function can only return one value and that, after a process split, each function *still* only returns a single value, it's just that there are two functions running (one per process). From what I can see, you comment says "no" then goes on to state what I've already stated :-) Unless I've missed something, entirely possible of course.

Comment: @paxdiablo: What you wrote may be clear to you, but it wasn't to me.  I can see, now, how it could be interpreted that way, but that wasn't my initial reading.  So I tried to make it clearer.

Comment: @jamesqf, okay, added a diagram which will hopefully make it a bit clearer. Any advice you have on how that could be done further would be appreciated.

Answer (score 30):

In Linux `fork()` happens in kernel; the actual place is the [`_do_fork` here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/5c9a8750a6409c63a0f01d51a9024861022f6593/kernel/fork.c#L1696). Simplified, the `fork()` system call could be something like

```
pid_t sys_fork() {
    pid_t child = create_child_copy();
    wait_for_child_to_start();
    return child;
}
```

So in the kernel, `fork()` really returns *once*, into the parent process. However the kernel also creates the child process as a copy of the parent process; but instead of returning from an ordinary function, it would synthetically create a new **kernel stack** for the newly created thread of the child process; and then context-switch to that thread (and process); as the newly created process returns from the context switching function, it would make the child process' thread end up returning to user mode with 0 as the return value from `fork()`.

---

Basically `fork()` in userland is just a thin wrapper returns the value that the kernel put onto its stack/into return register. The kernel sets up the new child process so that it returns 0 via this mechanism from its only thread; and the child pid is returned in the parent system call as any other return value from any system call such as `read(2)` would be.

Comment: "synthetically create a new stack for the child process" falls under the category of "copies the entire parent process's address space" - there's nothing different about that part.

Comment: @ClickRick no it absolutely **does not**. This is about kernel stack.

Comment: @ClickRick The child process' thread's kernel stack would be at another address, it cannot be copied.

Answer (score 10):

You first need to know how multitasking works. It is not useful to understand all the details, but every process runs in some kind of a virtual machine controlled by the kernel: a process has its own memory, processor and registers, etc. There is mapping of these virtual objects onto the real ones (the magic is in the kernel), and there is some machinery that swap virtual contexts (processes) to physical machine as time pass.

Then, when the kernel forks a process (`fork()` is an entry to the kernel), and creates a copy of almost everything in the *parent* process to the *child* process, it is able to modify everything needed. One of these is the modification of the corresponding structures to return 0 for the child and the pid of the child in the parent from current call to fork.

Note: nether say "fork returns twice", a function call returns only once.

Just think about a cloning machine: you enter alone, but two persons exit, one is you and the other is your clone (very slightly different); while cloning the machine is able to set a name different than yours to the clone.

Comment: Does `is an entry to the kernel` mean `syscall`?

Comment: That's it (in Unix family).

Comment: I was just curious about the wording :)

Answer (score 8):

The fork system call creates a new process and copies a lot of state from the parent process. Things like the file descriptor table gets copied, the memory mappings and their contents, etc. That state is inside the kernel.

One of the things the kernel keeps track for every process are the values of registers this process needs to have restored at the return from a system call, trap, interrupt or context switch (most context switches happen on system calls or interrupts). Those registers are saved on a syscall/trap/interrupt and then restored when returning to userland. System calls return values by writing into that state. Which is what fork does. Parent fork gets one value, child process a different one.

Since the forked process is different from the parent process, the kernel could do anything to it. Give it any values in registers, give it any memory mappings. To actually make sure that almost everything except the return value is the same as in the parent process requires more effort.

Answer (score 2):

For each running process, the kernel has a table of registers, to load back when a context switch is made. `fork()` is a system call; a special call that, when made, the process gets a context switch and the kernel code executing the call runs in a different (kernel) thread.

The value returned by system calls is placed in a special register (EAX in x86) that your application reads after the call. When the `fork()` call is made, the kernel makes a copy of the process, and in each table of registers of each process descriptor writes the appropiate value: 0, and the pid.