# How can _do_fork() return two different PIDs (one for the parent process and one for the child process)

Tags: c, linux, process, linux-kernel, fork

I was looking at the [`_do_fork()`](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/fork.c#L1967) function () trying to understand how `fork()` returns the child PID for the parent process and 0 on the child process.

I think that `nr` contains the PID of the child process (that will be returned to the caller process), but I can't see how it is able to return 0 to the child process.

The answer [How does fork() know when to return 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36640260/how-does-fork-know-when-to-return-0/36641065#36641065) says that the return value is passed on the stack created for the new process, but (besides not really understanding it) *I can't find that in the code*.

So, **where the return value of 0 is set for the child process?**

The code of the `_do_fork()` function is copied below:

```
long _do_fork(unsigned long clone_flags,
          unsigned long stack_start,
          unsigned long stack_size,
          int __user *parent_tidptr,
          int __user *child_tidptr,
          unsigned long tls)
{
    struct task_struct *p;
    int trace = 0;
    long nr;

    /*
     * Determine whether and which event to report to ptracer.  When
     * called from kernel_thread or CLONE_UNTRACED is explicitly
     * requested, no event is reported; otherwise, report if the event
     * for the type of forking is enabled.
     */
    if (!(clone_flags & CLONE_UNTRACED)) {
        if (clone_flags & CLONE_VFORK)
            trace = PTRACE_EVENT_VFORK;
        else if ((clone_flags & CSIGNAL) != SIGCHLD)
            trace = PTRACE_EVENT_CLONE;
        else
            trace = PTRACE_EVENT_FORK;

        if (likely(!ptrace_event_enabled(current, trace)))
            trace = 0;
    }

    p = copy_process(clone_flags, stack_start, stack_size,
             child_tidptr, NULL, trace, tls, NUMA_NO_NODE);
    add_latent_entropy();
    /*
     * Do this prior waking up the new thread - the thread pointer
     * might get invalid after that point, if the thread exits quickly.
     */
    if (!IS_ERR(p)) {
        struct completion vfork;
        struct pid *pid;

        trace_sched_process_fork(current, p);

        pid = get_task_pid(p, PIDTYPE_PID);
        nr = pid_vnr(pid);

        if (clone_flags & CLONE_PARENT_SETTID)
            put_user(nr, parent_tidptr);

        if (clone_flags & CLONE_VFORK) {
            p->vfork_done = &vfork;
            init_completion(&vfork);
            get_task_struct(p);
        }

        wake_up_new_task(p);

        /* forking complete and child started to run, tell ptracer */
        if (unlikely(trace))
            ptrace_event_pid(trace, pid);

        if (clone_flags & CLONE_VFORK) {
            if (!wait_for_vfork_done(p, &vfork))
                ptrace_event_pid(PTRACE_EVENT_VFORK_DONE, pid);
        }

        put_pid(pid);
    } else {
        nr = PTR_ERR(p);
    }
    return nr;
}
```

Comment: You want understand the code of linux, Some people tried but they had problems.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have correctly identified how the new process id is returned to the parent, with `return nr`. But you will never actually see a `return 0` anywhere since this code is executed on the parent thread. This code is not for the new process that is created.

Now let us examine the `_do_fork` function.

```
...
}
p = copy_process(clone_flags, stack_start, stack_size,
         child_tidptr, NULL, trace, tls, NUMA_NO_NODE);
add_latent_entropy();
...
```

This is where all the magic happens. When you call [copy_process](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/fork.c#L1491)
, it internally calls `copy_thread` which is a target specific code. This function is responsible for coping the thread related data structures.

Now say we have the target as X86_64 with the calling convention that the return value is returned in the `%rax` register. This function then copies `0` into `%rax` and copies the value of `return_from_fork` address to `%rip`(the instruction pointer).

On other platforms the ABI might require the return value to go on the stack. In that case `0` is placed on the stack. `copy_thread` is target specific but `copy_process` is not.

[This](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/arch/x86/kernel/process_64.c#L146) is the implementation of `copy_thread` for X86_64. You can see around line number 160 the sp registers being set. And at line 182 you can see `%ax` (which is a subregister of %rax) being set to 0.

I hope this clears some confusion.